# What is the $n$th term of the sequence $1, 1, 4, 1, 4, 9, 1, 4, 9, 16, 1 ...$

Tags: sequences-and-series

So there exist a lot of similar questions which ask the $n$th term of 
 
$$1^2 , (1^2 + 2^2) , (1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2) ... $$
Which have a simple answer as
$$T_n = n^3/3 + n^2/2 + n/6$$
But I want to know what will be the $n$th term if we consider each number as a single term. I tried making a pyramid of terms and got this

$1^2\\
1^2~2^2\\
1^2~2^2~3^2\\
1^2~2^2~3^2~4^2\\
...$

I got the $n$th term as$$T_n= (n\mod(m(m-1)/2)^2$$
Where $m$ is the row number.

> But now I am stuck, is there a way to eliminate $m$ and write the general term only in terms of $n$?

Comment: Hi Welcome! A good idea is to edit your question with MathJax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference This will help if you regularly going to ask questions and it avoids your question being downvoted.

Comment: $m$ is the smallest solution of $x(x+1)/2\ge n$, i.e. $\lceil\frac{-1+\sqrt{8n+1}}2\rceil$

Comment: See [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A133819).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OEIS](http://oeis.org/A133819) has an entry for this sequence. And they give a formula:

> `a(n) = A000290(m+1), where m = n-t(t+1)/2, t = floor((-1+sqrt(8*n-7))/2)`

The sequence named `A000290` is just the perfect squares, so `A000290(m+1)` means $(m+1)^2$. And $m$ is given as $n-\frac{t(t+1)}2$, where $t=\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{8n-7}-1}2\right\rfloor$. Nesting out all of this, the finished formula becomes
$$
\left(n-\frac{\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{8n-7}-1}2\right\rfloor\left(\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{8n-7}-1}2\right\rfloor+1\right)}{2}+1\right)^2
$$
where the brackets indicate the floor function.

Answer (score 1):

The number of terms in $x$ rows is $1+2+...+x=x(x+1)/2$. The row number $m$ of $n^{\text{th}}$ term is thus the smallest positive integer solution of $x(x+1)/2\ge n$. The roots of $x^2+x-2n=0$ are $\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{8n+1}}2$. First, we reject the negative root. Next, we take the ceiling value of the positive root as it may not be a whole number.

Thus,$$m=\left\lceil\frac{-1+\sqrt{8n+1}}2\right\rceil$$

---

As a side note, you can ditch the mod and use regular subtraction in your formula.